# Binding a collection to Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I basically started today with WPF, and I'm astounded by how difficult it is to do binding. I have an array of `TextBoxes`, in an `ObservableCollection`, and just want to bind that in my `Listbox`, so that they arrange themselves vertically.

I have fiddled around with this for 3 already, can you help?

I'm working in a WPF `UserControl`, not a window as so many tutorials seem to rely on.

Comment: Please don't jump to decide that data binding in WPF/Silverlight is difficult.  It turns out there is a very good rhyme and reason for everything, and it is actually quite easy, once you understand the paradigm.  There certainly is a learning curve to the paradigm, but once you get it, you will likely feel like data binding is the greatest thing... worlds better than Winforms, but that's not saying much :)

Comment: In wpf you don't need to create an array of textboxes. Just define the template containing a textbox and bind it to a list of data, `list.Count` number of textboxes are created for you on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your C# code, you can do something like this:

```
myListBox.ItemsSource = myTextBoxesCollection;
```

Or in your XAML code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyTextBoxesCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

For the XAML, MyTextBoxesCollection needs to be a public property on your data context. One way to set the DataContext could be, in your constructor:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  MyListBox should be ListBox, for one.  And in answer to your suspicion, it does not need to be a dependency property.

Comment: if I do this, it tells my: System.InvalidOperationException: Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.
even though I actually do assign it before I add textboxes.

Comment: When using an ItemsControl you must use either the Items property or the ItemsSource property, you can't use both at the same time. Make sure you aren't setting the content of the ListBox like this:

    <ListBox ....
        ... all that crap I show above ...
        <SomeItem />
        <SomeItem />
    </ListBox>

And make sure you aren't adding anything to the Items collection in your code behind either.

Comment: @Blurb: Still, I question why you are creating a collection of text boxes, and then binding the Text properties of them to a ListBox to create new TextBoxes.  Is this really what you want?  Or do you want a collection of strings?

Answer (score 3):

Having an `ObservableCollection<TextBox>` is alomost always the wrong approach.  You likely want an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead.

Then, in your ListBox (or ItemsCollection) you have the following code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to format `ObservableCollection<TextBox>` and `ObservableCollection<String>` as the first line has no meaning in it.

Comment: This does NOT work. I have tried this in every concievable way. Please create a WPF project yourself and try this.

Comment: Sorry... I missed the '.' in the {Binding .}

Answer (score 1):

Make MyTextBoxCollection (your ObservableCollection of textboxes) a public property of your DataContext.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource=”{Binding MyTextBoxCollection}”>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate><TextBox Text=”{Binding Text}” /></DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work. My listbox only shows "System.Windows.DataTemplate" in a single row. I'm adding this in the UserControl constructor though:
TextBox temp = new TextBox();
temp.Text = "Test";
collectedTodos.Add(temp);
Following error:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'mycollection' property not found on 'object' ''MyControl' (Name='Window')'. BindingExpression:Path=mycollection; DataItem='MyControl' (Name='Window'); target element is 'ListBox' (Name='Test2'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: @Blub: change your ItemsSource like this `<ListBox ItemsSource=”{Binding collectedTodos}”>`. Wrap the `<DataTemplate><TextBox Text=”{Binding Text}” /></DataTemplate>` block with `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` as in Brian's answer.

Comment: You are missing <ListBox.ItemTemplate> between the ListBox and DataTemplate

Comment: I still get the same error and nothing shows up in the listbox. I also get these: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBar', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DockLocation; DataItem=null; target element is 'VsMenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Comment: @Blub: What do you mean?  My answer is nearly identical to the accepted one.